# Proving Morera's Theorem through the Cauchy-Goursat theorem for rectangles

Tags: complex-analysis

In my book Morera's Theorem is stated as for if $f$ is a continuous function on an open set $U$, that has the property that around the boundary of any rectangle the closed integral is zero, then  $f$ is holomorphic.

I want to prove that this is equivalent to saying if $f$ is a continuous function on an open set $U$ that has the property $\oint f=0$ along any closed path in $U$, then $f$ his holomorphic.

A bit context: My book is Serge Lang's Introduction to Complex Analysis at an Undergraduate level. The book introduced the Cauchy-Goursat theorem for rectangles and then proved Cauchy's Integral Formula (for simply connected open sets)

**Question:**
Does anybody know how could I show that the conditions "around the boundary of any rectangle in $U$ the closed integral is zero" and "$\oint f$ along any closed path in $U$" are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two conditions are not equivalent. Here is a counterexample: Let $U:=U_1(0)\backslash U_r(0)$, where $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}<r<1$. That's a thin annulus with the inner and outer radius chosen such that no rectangle can can be drawn around the center of the annulus. Essentially, if you draw any rectangle inside a circle of radius $1$, you can't fit a circle with radius larger than $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ inside the rectangle. So with the chosen radii, the inner boundary will never be inside any rectangle inscribed into the annulus. If any rectangle is inscribed into the annulus, then the inside of the rectangle is a subset of $U$.

Now take $f:U\to\mathbb C,~z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$. According to the Goursat theorem, the integral $\oint_{\square}f(z)\mathrm dz$ along any rectangle $\square$ vanishes, since $f$ is holomorphic and the rectangle, including its interior, are included in $U$. But the integral $\oint_{\vert z\vert=\rho}f(z)\mathrm dz$ with $r<\rho<1$ is known to not vanish (it's $2\pi\mathrm i$).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I could be misunderstanding but isn't $f$ not continuous on $0$?

Comment: $0$ is not in the domain of $f$, so it doesn't make sense to talk about continuity there. Continuity is a feature of functions at points in their domain. Just imagine that there is no ambient space that could contain any problematic points. There is just an annulus floating in empty space, and there is a function defined on it, and at every point in the annulus, it is continuous.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I just have one more final question in my book the following theorem https://ibb.co/fSV5RT2 was used to prove Morera's theorem given here https://ibb.co/5n5N9FS (where theorem 7.2 is the equivalence of analicity and homomorphism). When I was looking at this proof I thought of constructing it as I had described before, but as you correctly pointed out it doesn't quite work. Do you know how this transition between open dics and open sets is made?

Comment: Complex differentiability is a property that only depends on the local behavior of a function. Take any point in the domain, and any neighborhood of the point, and complex differentiability in the point is then completely determined by how the function looks on the neighborhood, no matter how small the neighborhood is. In particular, complex differentiability in a point is fully determined by how the function looks on an open disc around the point. So if a function is holomorphic on discs, it is automatically holomorphic on its entire domain.

Comment: ahh I understand. I just want to also clarify something, in the book it says that this theorem is Morera's Theorem, however, when I looked it up the condition for homomorphism is $\oint f = 0$ rather than the integral over rectangular path condition. As you saw in my other comments, I tried to prove that they are same conditions but you rightfully pointed out that they are not. My question is does that mean that they are different theorems?

Comment: There are several versions of Morera's theorem. All require $f$ to be continuous, and all require the integrals along certain contours to vanish (all triangles, all rectangles, all polygons, all contours), but there's one slight difference: some versions only require the integral to vanish when the interior of the contour is also part of the domain, while others require the integral to vanish no matter how the interior is situated relative to the domain. The former version is stronger and implies the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out, if anybody sees any error in this please feel free to correct me. I will prove this as an iff statement.

First, we will consider the rectangle assumption.

If the closed integral along any rectangular path is zero then by the Gourast theorem we can define $U$ as a union of discs (defined by each rectangle) on which $f$ is holomorphic. Since $f$ is holomorphic it follows that $f's$ primitive along a path is a series of local primitives defined by the different discs (which are defined from the different rectangles). Since the primative exists it follows that $\oint f=0$ for any closed path.

We will now consider the assumption $\oint f =0$ first.

If $\oint f = 0$ for all closed paths in $U$. Then we can consider all rectangles inscribed in $U$ as such paths from which we get $\oint_{\partial R} f=0$.

Hence the iff statement is true.

If this is wrong please correct me.

Comment: "by the Gourast theorem we can define U as a union of discs (defined by each rectangle)". Can you elaborate on this? The Goursat theorem says that if a function is holomorphic and a rectangle is fully included in its domain, then the integral along the boundary of the rectangle vanishes. What does that have to do with writing the domain as a union of discs? And what does it mean to define a disc by a rectangle?

Comment: Hi @Vercassivelaunos apologies for the unclarity. I meant the converse of Goursat's theorem. Thus if for every rectangle, the closed integral along the boundary is $0$ then $f$ is holomorphic. Now consider the following construction. Since $U$ can be any open set, not nessesarally simply connected, we can't use the Cauchy Integral Thoerem and thus we consider $U$ as the  union  of all open discs that can make $U$. Each of these open dics can contain an infinite amount of different rectangles of different sizes.

Comment: Thus, assuming all that the integral along every rectangle in $U$ is zero we get that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$. Since $f$ is holomorphic, the primitive of $f$ along any path $\gamma$, no matter closed or not, will be given as a sum of local primitives (by partitioning the path and constructing discs in which the local primitive exists). Now since the primitive exists it follows that $\oint f = 0$ for any closed path in $U$.

Comment: There is a gap in your argument why a primitive exists. Local primitives exist for $1/z$, and all integrals can be written as sums of differences of such local primitives, but that doesn't mean that a global primitive exists.